# Detecting a blank line in C++ from reading a file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, if-statement, delimiter

I have a plain text file (.txt) with the following data;

```
data 5

data 7
data 8
```

I read this file in the following manner:

```
 ifstream myReadFile;
 myReadFile.open(fileName.c_str());

 if (myReadFile.is_open() != true){
    return -1;
 }

string stri;
int i;

while (std::getline(myReadFile,stri)){
  i++;
  if(stri.find("data") != std::string::npos){ //extract data}

  else if(stri.empty()){ cout << "Conditional statement true"; }

  else { cout << "invalid keyword on line: " << i; }
}
```

I always receive the invalid keyword message and never does the conditional statement go through. I have tried if (stri == "") and (stri.compare("");

NOTE: It is safe to assume that the empty line contains NO WHITESPACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to find the contents of the line that seems to be a problem.

```
else {
   cout << "invalid keyword on line: " << i;
   size_t size = stri.size();
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   {
     // Print the ASCII code of the character.
     cout << "ASCII code: " << (int)stri[i] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Find out what the ASCII codes represent from [an ASCII code table](http://www.asciitable.com/). That will indicate what's being read into the line. It is most likely a carriage return, `\r`, with ASCII code `13`.

Comment: Yes, I did get a 13 ASCII code. I have tried if (stri == "\r") and my problems seem to be tamed for now, however, another small question popped into my head. Would this work for files created both in UNIX and DOS? If not, what adjustment should I make?

Comment: @HaniAl-shafei, If the file is created in Windows, you'll have to convert to UNIX style line endings, and vice versa. When I encounter such files, I use two utility programs - `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`. They are usually installed cygwin. They are probably available on Linux desktops too.